# bubble builderでAPIを使用

Tags: api

bubble builderでAPIを使用したいと思っています。

プログラミング初心者です。

https://make.dmm.com/print/developer/creator/reference/

でgetで情報を取得はできたのですが、

postの使い方がわかりません。

postとはなんでしょうか？？？

途中まではなんとかできている気はするのですが、、、

headerにContent-Type、application/jsonを入力して

あとはBody (JSON object, use <> for dynamic values)のみだと思います。

bubbleで下記の物を作りました。

https://using-api.bubbleapps.io/version-test?debug_mode=true

postmanを使えばいいのでしょうか？？？

お願いします。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/145578

Comment: Reference | Bubble #API Connector
https://bubble.is/reference#Plugins.apiconnector2

Comment: Build a BMI calculator in Bubble on Vimeo
https://vimeo.com/162728948

Comment: Build a BMI calculator in Bubble on Vimeoをみましたが、まだなんとなくしかわかりません。。。